# (Bash) In while loop, what's the difference of commands before 'do'?

Tags: bash, while-loop

I saw some people putting codes before 'do'.

---

Question 1:
What's the difference between two loops, `function_1` and `function_2`?

```
a=1;b=1;c=1;d=1

function_1()
{
  while true
  ((a+=1))
  ((b+=1))
  do
    ((c+=1))
    ((d+=1))
    echo $a $b $c $d
    sleep 1
  done
}

function_2()
{
  while true
  do
    ((a+=1))
    ((b+=1))
    ((c+=1))
    ((d+=1))
    echo $a $b $c $d
    sleep 1
  done
}
```

---

Question 2:
What is `do` in loop command? Is it a command or a word delimiter? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between two loops

They have different conditional and body commands lists.

The overall rule is that the exit status of almost anything in shell is the exit status of last command executed. The first loop executes a list of 3 commands

```
while
   true
   (( a += 1 ))
   (( b += 1 ))
do
```

[`while`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_09) body executes if the exit status of the conditional list is zero. The exit status of the list of 3 commands is equal to the exit status of last command executed `(( b += 1 ))`. The exit status of *arithmetic expression* `((....))` is zero, if the expression inside is equal to non-zero. The result of `+=` operator is equal to the assigned value.

`b` starts with value `1`, and then is added is `+= 1`. When it will overflow, after ~2^64 iterations, `b` will come back to zero, in which case the arithmetic expression will exit with non-zero exit status, in which case the loop will terminate.

The second loop just executes `true`, which always exits with zero exit status.

> What is do in loop command? What does it do?

Starts the body of the loop.

> Is it a command or a word delimiter?

Technically, it's a [*reserved word*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04).

Comment: So we could say that then `true` is totally unnecessary in function_1?

Comment: Yes, `true` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Reserved-Words, 'do' is a reserved word in this case.  It's acting as a delimiter.

The difference in your two examples is that `function_1` has a loop condition of `true ((a+=1)) ((b+=1))` whereas in `function_2` the loop condition is just `true`.  That is, `function_1` is incrementing `a` and `b` as it determines whether to loop or not, whereas `function_2` increments them within the loop itself.  Significantly, `function_1` loop condition `true ((a+=1)) ((b+=1))` evaluates to the last expression `((b+=1))` which causes it to loop.

The difference can be seen if you replace `true` with `false`, where the loop condition for `function_1` becomes `false ((a+=1)) ((b+=1))`, which will always loop, whereas `function_2` does not loop.

Comment: Interesting that `false; ((a+=1)); ((b+=1));` returns true. I assume it's using `$?` and  `((a+=1)); ((b+=1)); false; ` won't loop? So using independent variable(a,b) for an example was not my brightest idea.